# Why is a dictionary that I define in one module not allowed to be mutated by a second module?

Tags: .net, f#

I define an empty mutable dictionary in my first module via `let mutable`. In a subsequent module (which is aware of the first module) I try to add a key-value pair to the dictionary but this code never runs (but does compile successfully). Why?

On the other hand, it appears that a dictionary can be mutated successfully **within** the module that it is defined in.

## CODE

File1.fs

```
module File1
let mutable dictionary = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>()
```

File2.fs

```
module File2
File1.dictionary.Add("one",1)
```

Program.fs

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
printfn "%A" File1.dictionary.["one"]
0 // return an integer exit code
```

Error received:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: some code would help

Comment: @MattBurland code added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have anything that calls the code in `File2`.  The proper way to do this is within a function, so

File2.fs

```
module File2
let addOne() = File1.dictionary.Add("one", 1)
```

Program.fs

```
let main _ =
  File2.addOne()
  printfn....
```

That said, global mutable state is generally avoided in F#; it'd be more idiomatic to have a `File1.createDict()`, and then pass that into `File2.addOne` as a parameter, not to store it as a global variable.

Side note you don't actually need the `mutable` marker there, as that means the dictionary reference itself is mutable, not just its contents (which are always mutable by the definition of `Dictionary`).

Comment: Thanks, your answer works. However, why would calling `dictionary.Add...` stand-alone in `File1.fs` have the effect of mutating the dictionary's contents?

Comment: The whole point of the dictionary's Add method is to mutate the dictionary's contents. That's what it's for.

Comment: @Sam you're asking why it worked in File1 but not in File2? This is because standalone code in a module gets put into a Static Constructor (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).  Per the docs, "It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced".  In your Program.fs, you referenced `File1.dictionary`, causing File1's static constructor to get called, but never referenced anything on `File2`, so that code never got called.  If you add something else to File2 and call it from `main` then File2's static ctor will get called

Comment: @Sam not that I recommend taking that approach...static constructors aren't really a good pattern except for very specific cases, since seemingly unrelated code changes can affect whether they get called or not, as you can see.